# How to get data from a column that does not have a specific character?

Tags: sql

I have a table which have a column member_name varchar(25)

```
select member_name from member
```

How can i make a query where I can output the data that does not include the '/' character?
usually some of the data is like

'doe/john'
or 'doe john'

I use sql server 2008.

Answer (score 4):

```
select member_name from member Where member_name Not like '%/%'
```